# Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product::getMainTaxon() returns proxy insead of Taxoninterface

Tags: sylius

`getMainTaxon()` returns Proxy instead of TaxonInterface

I am doing migration from sylius 1.1 to sylius 1.5. Everything works fine except this error. I have no idea what should i do with this error.

My `_sylius.yaml` contains these entries:

```
sylius_product:
    resources:
        product:
            classes:
                repository: App\Repository\ProductRepository
                model: App\Entity\Product
                controller: App\Controller\ProductController
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: App\Entity\ProductTranslation

sylius_taxonomy:
    resources:
        taxon:
            classes:
                repository: App\Repository\TaxonRepository
                model: App\Entity\Taxon
```

My `doctrine.yaml` looks like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: UTF8

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: yml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/doctrine'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Full error looks like this

> Return value of Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product::getMainTaxon() must be an instance of Sylius\Component\Core\Model\TaxonInterface or null, instance of Proxies__CG__\App\Entity\Taxon returned

Do you know what can cause this error and how to manage it?

Comment: Could you show how you call `getMainTaxon()` please?

Comment: @Dr.X On the product grid in admin panel there is position MainTaxon so it is called by sylius_admin_product grid like this

                mainTaxon:
                    type: twig
                    label: sylius.ui.main_taxon
                    options:
                        template: "@SyliusAdmin/Product/Grid/Field/mainTaxon.html.twig"

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to solve this issue. Maybe it will help someone who migrates an application from legacy sylius.

In the past, I extended the Taxon entity and my Taxon.php looked like this

```
use Sylius\Component\Taxonomy\Model\Taxon as BaseTaxon;

class Taxon extends BaseTaxon {
```

The issue was I should have extended `Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon` class so my entity file now looks like this

```
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon as BaseTaxon;

class Taxon extends BaseTaxon {
```